# How can I get response header using AJAX

Tags: ajax, header

I'm trying to get response header using AJAX, but it doesn't work. Apparently I did't do it right:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url:'http://www.somesite.com/',
data: formData,
success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
alert(XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
  }
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
  }
});
```

I also try this one:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'http://www.somesite.com/',
complete: function(xhr) {
alert(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
  }
});
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the error message you get? What happens?

Comment: In console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma.

```
success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
    alert(XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
},   // <-------------
```

Comment: I added comma, but still doesn't work. Console: Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined.

Comment: I'm not psychic, I have no idea what formData is. Do you declare it? What is its value?